# Grails cloudfoundry plugin error

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I am trying to connect to my account , every cf-* script I run , i face the following error :

> error running script cf-info:
>   org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on
>   POST request for
>   "http://api.cloudfoundry.com/users/*****/tokens":api.cloudfoundry.com;
>   nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   api.cloudfoundry.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"api.cloudfoundry.com" is the URL for the hosted Cloud Foundry v1, which no longer exists.

The  Cloud Foundry Grails plugin has not been updated to support CF v2 yet. You should use the "cf" CLI to interact with CF instead of the Grails plugin scripts. See http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/using/managing-apps/cf/index.html and http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/using/deploying-apps/jvm/index.html.